# Is it possible to use Foundry to monitor the mempool?

Tags: solidity, txpool, foundry

I have been able to use other frameworks / libraries (e.g., web3.py and ethers.py) to monitor mempool events.

I see that anvil has one mention in the docs related to mempool monitoring (a switch for FIFO ordering of mempool events).  I also see there is a reference to `txpool_inspect`, but I'm assuming that's just related to a geth client and not something I can leverage in actual Solidity code of my script.

Because Foundry relies on Solidity for its scripting environment, I don't know how to make direct calls to a node so I can obtain mempool events.

Do I have to leverage Hardhat and JS inputs if I want to read from the mempool while running a Foundry Solidity script?

Comment: Mabye ask in the foundry support group: https://t.me/foundry_support

Comment: I was informed that Foundry is for development security testing and not actual operational security.  Therefore capabilities like front-running exploits are beyond Foundry's scope.  Unless someone has a better idea and can correct me on here.